# KnitR, Rnw, highR Error in def, sng color not being created

Tags: python, latex, knitr

Recently when compiling an Rnw file that generated python code output into a pdf, I ran into an error with the highR package.

It appears after debugging it myself that the code flags for color highlighting is not creating a \hldef and \hlsng in LaTeX. It’s easily fixed by adding these color codes.

So clearly it’s not creating these color codes. Is there a reason for this? I see from the GitHub source for highR that sng and def codes are not created.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you define `hldef` and `hlsng` to fix the problem?

Comment: A pseudo-fix, I grabbed one of the other macros, i.e, hlkwd. Replacing the command with hldef and hlsng fixed the problem. 

I’m wondering if something I’m doing is causing these two commands to not be created.